# how to save Multidimensional input text values in servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I am creating questionnaire web application where user build question with multiple options.My problem is that, I do not have any idea on how to pass multiple items or data on a form. And even what to put on a name attribute of an . Also, if the user add more items! How could I pass these unexpected number of data

So please give me some idea

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');  
        const $previewid = $('#preview');
        let passengerCounter=0;
        var optioncount=0;
        var radiocount=0;
        var maxoption = 7;
        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        
        $("select.form-control").change(function(){
            var option = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            if(option=="multiple")
                $.fn.callMultiple();
            else if(option=="single")
                $.fn.callSingle();
            else if(option=="short")
                $.fn.callShort();
            else if(option=="long")
                $.fn.callLong();
            else
                alert("Please select from options");
        });
$.fn.callMultiple = function() {
                $('#newSurvey').empty();
                optioncount=3;
                var selectType = $('#answerType').val();
                alert(selectType);
                let $newrow1='<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]"  id="option_">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="optcounter[]"></div>'+
                '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]"  id="option_">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="optcounter[]"></div>'+
                '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]"  id="option_">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="optcounter[]"></div>'+
                '<div id="rowmulti"></div>'+
                '&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button"  id="addmulti" class="addmulti" name="multi_add" style="background-color:green;color:white;">Add</button>'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="stype[]" id="stypeid" value="">';
                $('#newSurvey').append($newrow1);
            }
            
            $.fn.callSingle = function() {
                $('#newSurvey').empty();
                radiocount=2;
                var selectType = $('#answerType').val();
                alert(selectType);
                let $newrow2='<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optradio" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]" id="option_">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="radiocounter"></div>'+
                '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optradio" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]" id="option_">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="radiocounter"></div>'+
                '<div id="rowsingle"></div>'+
                '<button type="button"  id="addsingle" class="addsingle" name="single_add" style="background-color:green;color:white;">Add</button>'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="stype[]" id="stypeid" value="">';
                $('#newSurvey').append($newrow2); 
            }
    
            $.fn.callShort = function() {
                $('#newSurvey').empty();
                var selectType = $('#answerType').val();
                alert(selectType);
                let $newrow3='<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]" class="form-control" id="shortans" width="200px"><br><br>'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="stype[]" id="stypeid" value="">';
                $('#newSurvey').append($newrow3);
              } 
            
            $.fn.callLong = function() {
                $('#newSurvey').empty();
                var selectType = $('#answerType').val();
                alert(selectType);
                let $newrow4=' <label for="longanswer">Comment:</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name ="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]" id="longans></textarea>><br><br>'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="stype[]" id="stypeid" value="">';
                $('#newSurvey').append($newrow4);
             }

    $('#addSurvey').on('click',function(e)
                    {
                        
                        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                        var selectType = $('#answerType').val();
                        var title = $('#surveyName').val();
                        var question = $('#questionName').val();
                        if(selectType == "" || title == "" || question == "")
                        {
                            alert("Please enter your values");
                            return;
                        }
                        passengerCounter++;
                        $('#stypeid').val(selectType);
                        var select = $('#stypeid').val();
                        alert("hidden select type = "+select);
                        const uprow='<br>&nbsp;<label> '+passengerCounter+' </label><input type="text" id="questionName" name="questionName[]" class="form-control" value="'+question+'" readonly><br><br>';;
                        const $firstRow = $('#newSurvey').find(":input").not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=number]');
                        let $newrowhtml = $firstRow.clone(true);
                        $('#subsection').find("input").val("");
                        $('input[name="sname"]').val(title);
                        $previewid.prepend($newrowhtml);
                        $previewid.prepend(uprow);
                        $previewid.find("*").attr('readonly','readonly');
                    });
$("#newSurvey").on('click', '.addmulti', function() {
        optioncount++;
        let $newrow='<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]"  id="option_">'+
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="radiocounter">'+
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button"  id="multi_delete" name="multi_delete" class="multidelete" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Delete</button></div>';
        $('#rowmulti').append($newrow);
    });
    
    $("#newSurvey").on('click', '.addsingle', function() {
        if(radiocount>maxcount) 
        radiocount++;
            let $newrow='<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="optradio" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="questionName['+passengerCounter+']option[]" id="option_">'+
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="radiocounter">'+
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button"  id="multi_delete" name="multi_delete"class="singledelete" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Delete</button></div>';
            $('#rowsingle').append($newrow);
        });
    $("#newSurvey").on('click', '.multidelete', function() {
        optioncount--;
        $('#opid').val(optioncount);
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    $("#newSurvey").on('click', '.singledelete', function() {
        radiocount--;
        $('#rdid').val(radiocount);
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });

html 

    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surveyName" readonly name="surveyName" value="<%= request.getAttribute("surveyName") %> ">
        </div>
        <div id="subsection">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="questionName">Enter Question:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="questionName" name="questionName[]">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="answerType">
                <option value="">None</option>
                <option value="multiple">Multiple Choice type</option>
                <option value="single">Single Choice Type</option>
                <option value="short">Short Answer Type</option>
                <option value="long">Long Answer Type</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="newSurvey">
            
        </div>
```

trying to access in servlet

```
String surveyName ;
        String questionName[] = null;
        String[] selectType = null;
        String[][] option =null;
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        surveyName = request.getParameter("surveyName");
        out.println("survey name=>"+surveyName);
        if(request.getParameterValues("stype[]")!=null)
        {
            selectType= request.getParameterValues("stype[]");
            for(i=0;i<selectType.length;i++)
            {
                out.println("select type = >" +selectType[i]);
            }
        }
        if(request.getParameterValues("questionName[]")!=null)
        {
            questionName = request.getParameterValues("questionName[]");
            for(i=0;i<questionName.length;i++)
            {
                out.println("qustion name = >" +questionName[i]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<questionName.length;i++)
        {
            String[] val =  request.getParameterValues("questionName[].option[]");
            for(int j=0;j<val.length;j++)
            {
                option[i][j]=val[j];
                out.println("option =>"+option[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: where is `$previewid` in your code ? and `passengerCounter` ? please add code related to this.

Comment: @swati I have edited the code

Comment: I am not getting how to access option[] values For each question there are variable no of options

Comment: If I am trying with getParameterMap() it return <string,string[]> values how I can use to store in database

Comment: you can access value of options like this `request.getParameterValues(questionName["+i+"]option[])`  inside for loop where `i` will be 0 , 1 ..etc and then get it in `val[j]` no need to store that in `option[i][j]`

Comment: String[] val =  request.getParameterValues(questionName["+i+"]option[]); while accessing like this showing error

Comment: questionName["+i+"]option[] showing syntax mismatch error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218298/discussion-between-swati-and-jyotsna-shekhar).